# netty writeAndFlush https datagram does not get response

Tags: java, https, netty

Refer to netty example in package *io.netty.example.proxy* ,it works well both http and https, even https message is garbled.

I want to use netty to excute a https message got from a proxy server.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Bootstrap b;
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup;
    ChannelFuture f;

    workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(workerGroup);
    b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    b.option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    b.handler(new HttpForwardHandler());
    f = b.connect(ip, port);
}

public class HttpForwardHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
@Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {

        String content = ""//datagram got from proxy
        ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(content .getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        ctx.writeAndFlush(buf )
        .addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    ctx.read();
                } else {
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
          //can not get https response here
    }

}
```

*version:netty-all-4.1.9-Final*

when I tried to writeAndFlush a http message,it worked,but https message did not.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the write futures `cause()` to understand why it not worked.